# UWP CreateDDSTextureFromFile unable to loard .dds file

Tags: c++, uwp, directx-11

I'm currently trying to get a .dds file onto a cube, but having trouble loading in the file.

I'm using the DirectXTK libaries from nuget, more specificly the DDSTextureLoarder.

```
CreateDDSTextureFromFile(m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice(), L"..\Assests\rocks.DDS", nullptr, &cubeStoneRV);
```

The error that comes up:

Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateFileW@28 referenced in function "long __cdecl DirectX::LoaderHelpers::LoadTextureDataFromFile(wchar_t const *,class std::unique_ptr > &,struct DirectX::DDS_HEADER const * *,unsigned char const * *,unsigned int *)" (?LoadTextureDataFromFile@LoaderHelpers@DirectX@@YAJPB_WAAV?$unique_ptr@$$BY0A@EU?$default_delete@$$BY0A@E@std@@@std@@PAPBUDDS_HEADER@2@PAPBEPAI@Z)

I believe that the problem lies with trying to get the D3DDevice, yet everything I have tried hasn't worked.

The work is started from the base UWP DirectX11 template and outside Sample3DSceneRenderer/phc, nothing else has changed.

edit: If there is a better way of doing this, im open for advice/suggestions

Comment: Double check MSDN but I don't think you can load a texture from file in UWP. I think you have to compile it into the resources of the binary.

Comment: @Mgetz The only limitation is if you are trying to load a file from outside your package, like from a user's Documents or Pictures library which requires using a file broker. You can still use DDSTextureLoader on such files but have to copy it to a temporary location first. See the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader#windows-store-apps) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UWP you cannot use `CreateFile`. You must use `CreateFile2`.

```
    #if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
        ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(CreateFile2(fileName,
                           GENERIC_READ,
                           FILE_SHARE_READ,
                           OPEN_EXISTING,
                           nullptr)));
    #else
        ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(CreateFileW(fileName,
                           GENERIC_READ,
                           FILE_SHARE_READ,
                           nullptr,
                           OPEN_EXISTING,
                           FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                           nullptr)));
    #endif
```

I do this in [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK) already, but you need to use the correct build configuration of the library. Likely you are using the [desktop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/directxtk_desktop_2015/) NuGet version rather than the [UWP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/directxtk_uwp/) NuGet version.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, i was indeed using the desktop version instead of the UWP, changing it let me compile again!